# Financial Random Walks

Tags: references, finance, random-walk, stochastic-calculus

Does anyone know of any good and accessible papers on the random walk modelling of financial data from a statistics perspective? Most of the papers I've found have been written by economists or suchlike, and while still mathematical, they don't quite have the theoretical depth I would like.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

[http://www.amazon.com/Brownian-Stochastic-Calculus-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387976558/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387976558)

I thin it is more theoretically oriented than normal finance textbooks for MBA's.